# Entity mapping is creating unwanted column on the fly

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have 2 tables (User and Feed) linked by a foreign key. Following that, I am using Spring Boot and Hibernate to make a query to just print out all the values in Feed table. But when it comes to the foreign key and its value, my Entity seems to be going wrong where it creates a new column on the fly when I already have a column for the foreign key.

Can I please know what I am doing wrong? New to this JPA setup. Confused as to whether I should even create my schema first or let JPA just handle things according to my Entity setups. Clearly I am missing something vital this but just can't place a finger on it. Please assist.

Question is how do I map to the foreign key? As in map Feed table's foreign key **'owner_name'** to User table's **'username'** on the Entity?

Table structures

[image]

Entities

User Entity

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "username")
    public String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    public String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    public String password;

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Column(name = "online_status")
    private long onlineStatus;

    @Column(name = "account_status")
    private long accountStatus;

    //updated this based on Gopi's suggestion
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ownerName")
    private List<Feed> feeds;
}
```

Feed Entity

```
@Entity
public class Feed {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "feed_id")
    private long feedId;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Date updatedAt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "username")
//    @Column(name = "owner_name")
    private User ownerName;
}
```

My query to just get all the Feed data where I do get all data less the value for foreign key which comes out as null. (expecting to get the foreign key value instead).

My controller is calling this method where I get all results less the foreign key value.

```
public interface FeedRepository extends JpaRepository<Feed, Long> {
    @Query("select f from Feed as f order by f.createdAt desc")
    List<Feed> getCurrentFeeds();
}
```

Test values inside the tables.

User table data

[image]

Feed table data

[image]

If I run my current code, I end up with an additional column on the fly as follows which I do not want as mentioned above.

[image]

Comment: You need to create a bidirectional mapping i.e., both one to many and many to one. Refer to this [link] https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many

Comment: Try to replace your join column description with `@JoinColumn(name = "ownerName")`

Comment: @Gopi I will look it up but is that a must though? Cos currently do not have a need for User table to reference Feed table.

Comment: Yes, when you define foreign key relationship if your parent has child records or not , you still have to define the mapping. Otherwise, hibernate will create unwanted columns or tables.

Comment: @Gopi I removed that additional column and added following to the Feed Entity based on that link. But still same results where the additional column got created again. @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ownerName") private List<Feed> feeds;

Comment: @Trevor_zam can you update your new entities code above?

Comment: @Gopi I meant to say I updated the User table. I have updated the question above. Also commented above the change - // updated this based on Gopi's suggestion

Comment: Your code has `@JoinColumn(name = "username")`. But the actual name of the join column in the table is `owner_name`, not `username`. Use the correct join column name: `owner_name`.

Comment: @JBNizet switching the joinColumn name to 'owner_name' under Feed entity stops creating the additional column but ended up in a StackOverflowError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is not surprising, you have specified as a name attribute to the @JoinColumn the column that is actualy referenced. You need to specify the foreign key column in the Feed table which is the "owner_name". The correct complete definition of the @JoinColumn would be:

```
@JoinColumn(name="owner_name",referencedcolumn = "username")
    private User ownerName;
```

Where you don't actualy need to define the referencedcolumn, but I have defined it for completion so that you understand what is what.

Comment: Perfect. Works now. Very confused though. I could have sworn I got a stackoverflow error when I don't use the referencedcolumn = "username". But right now it is working with or without it.... Unfortunately unable to recreate the error..

Comment: @Trevor_zam you don't need the referencedcolumn, the default value generated by hibernate is sensible when the referenced column is the PK. Your error was that you had specified in the begining @JoinColumn(name="username")   :) instead of @JoinColumn(name="owner_name")

Comment: I get what you mean. But I did correct that as per the advice by JB Nizet in the comments above. Not sure what I missed but I must have done something wrong. Thanks it works now.